# Adding Sections to Body of Form - is there any means to make a section Single column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, multiple-lines-of-text

I do not think there is any means to do this but thought I should ask - when creating sections in the Body, this will make the fields appear as multi-column which is fine mostly.

The issue is that some of the columns contain detailed text and would look much better if they were as per what they look without sections.

Expecting the solution is PowerApps but asking in case there is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet in SharePoint online by formatting body layout in list forms.

Microsoft might be bringing this feature in future, but no ETA/timelines.

[image]

**Documentation**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

---

So, you have to customize the list forms using Power Apps or [SharePoint framework form customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer)